# How Get-AzVM return Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine vs Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachineInstanceView?

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I'm trying to update a windows vm to have a system assigned managed identity.

I tried using the following commands.

```
$Vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vm_name -ResourceGroupName $rg -Status
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -VM $vm -IdentityType SystemAssigned
```

I'm getting the error message

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachineInstanceView" value of type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachineInstanceView" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the -Status flag on Get-AzVM returns a different object than without the -Status flag.

Try removing it and you will get an object that is compatible with Update-VM

```
$Vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vm_name -ResourceGroupName $rg
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the script is lil wrong with the variables, let me give you an updates script, hopefully it will works.

```html
# Get the VM
$Vm = Get-AzVM -Name $vm_name -ResourceGroupName $rg -Status

# Update the VM with SystemAssigned Managed Identity
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -VM $Vm -IdentityType SystemAssigned
```